# Is it possible for USB HSDPA modems to receive MMS messages?

Tags: mms, gsm

I'm using a Huawei E220 USB modem to send and receive SMS messages. I have it plugged into my Ubuntu laptop and am using Gammu to manage it. However this modem I think only works with SMS (text) messages.

Are there any HSDPA/GSM/GPRS modems that can receive MMS messages?

Answer (score 1):

The E220 is an ordinary modem that is capable of all the things that modems are capable of. It is a full internet connection, so you can send and receive anything that you can access on the internet with any other connection type. You can access web pages, do downloads, and send both SMS and MMS messages.

If you do not have that capability, then the program that is managing it is the limitation.

Comment: Well if that's the case, does the modem store the MMS message on its internal memory or its getting passed on to the PC?

Answer (score 0):

Any data enabled modem (GPRS, HSDPA, CDMA) etc is capable of posting MMS messages via HTTP or UDP to the host cellular network. The limitations exist around the carriers implementation of their MMS gateway and understanding what format they require which is dependent on which MMS gateway they are running on their network.

Receiving messages is a little more involved - an incoming MMS is triggered by a binary SMS formatted as an MMS Notification - this tells the wireless modem where to pull down the message from.